# Setting a varchar column length with a variable or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I have a table that is created by an import of an Excel file. As is the case, all text fields are imported as nvarchar(255). I'd rather do the bulk import then manipulate the table afterwards. I know SSIS allows me to set data types and sizes via data mapping, but that doesn't seem to work consistently for me. Maybe I'm not holding my mouth right...

Anyway, I want to change the varchar length definitions to the max length of the data in each column. Rather than run a statement to check the max length as a literal...

```
select max(len(rtrim(FIELD))) from TABLE$
```

...I want to do it in code. So I hit on this idea:

```
declare @Var int
set @Var = (select max(len(rtrim(FIELD))) from TABLE$)
alter table dbo.TABLE$ alter column FIELD varchar(@Var)
```

Lines one and two work fine, but it gives me an error when executing the third line:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '@Var'.

So I tried this, thinking it would be a more compact solution...

```
alter table dbo.TABLE$ 
  alter column FIELD varchar(select max(len(rtrim(FIELD))) from TABLE$)
```

...but it wasn't. I got these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

So my question is kind of a two-parter. First, why won't these methods work, and second, what would work--short of finding the mas length of each column, then setting the `varchar` length with a literal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: might have to be done as full dynamic SQL...set a variable to be the sql statement with the alter table then execute it.  Mind if I ask..what advantage are you going for in setting this field to be the max len(column)?

Comment: So if you have a column that is `NVARCHAR(255)` and the max value *currently* stored in it is 86 characters, why do you think `VARCHAR(86)` is a better choice than `VARCHAR(255)`? Why do you think `VARCHAR` is better than `NVARCHAR`? Setting the length shorter could restrict your ability to capture similar data in the future, and *not* using Unicode in cases where it might be needed means you could lose data now, during the conversion, or later. I strongly recommend you set the data types based on business rules and data collection policies, not observed max length in this batch.

Comment: ...that means actually *thinking* about each column, and what kind of data you *might* expect to see there now and in the future. If this is for a one-time import and you're actually going to throw the table away and re-use it, don't bother changing the columns. You don't *lose* anything by having a column support 255 characters but only ever store up to 86. It's not like SQL Server reserves all 255 characters for you.

Comment: These days there's no real advantage to having a column defined as varchar(86) vs. (n)varchar(255). It's a personal preference that I have had ever since I switched careers to IT over 20 years ago. Back in those days there were efforts to conserve space whenever and wherever possible; such as a two-digit year vs. a four digit year (hence the panic over Y2K). Early on in my career I was encouraged to consider overhead, so I developed this "ideology" and have used it ever since.

Comment: Over those years I discovered a downside to increased disk capacity, which is sloppy and bloated coding. The reasoning behind this was, "Hey! Disk space is cheap." I never really bought into that philosophy, which is why I try to conserve space whenever possible. The table is a one-time load for a specific process. After that process has run, it will be truncated and used again. But subsequent loads may very well have different length data in the fields, which is what generated my question.

Comment: Leaving them as (n)varchar(255) would probably be the best solution, but old habits die hard. :-) Thanks for your input, though.

Comment: But my point was that (n)varchar(255) doesn't take any more space than (n)varchar(86), unless you actually store more than 86 characters, in which case it only takes up more space in the rows that need it. This is not a fixed width format file from the 80s. If you make it (n)varchar(86) and you later need to store 87 characters, what are you going to do?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. My script covers the event of a subsequent increase in field length. But I'm trying to train myself to move away from how I've been doing it over the years. Believe me, your comments haven't fallen on deaf ears. Just old, "set-in-my-ways" ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL would work for what you're trying to do. Whether it's the right tool for the job or the right thing to do is another story. Give this a shot:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Table$ ALTER COLUMN FIELD VARCHAR(' + CAST((SELECT MAX(LEN(RTRIM(FIELD))) FROM dbo.TABLE$) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ')'
EXEC(@cmd)
```

That query parses but I didn't try to run it. Be careful using Dynamic SQL though. It can get you into trouble if you start using it everywhere. Further reading:

http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html